# Netlify not detecting NextJS Material-UI contact form

Tags: next.js, material-ui, netlify

## Netlify form with MUI and NextJS not working

I am just getting to start with NextJS and I created a component which is a plain and simple contact form made with MUI. I'm calling the component inside the index page and the form is not being detected by netlify.
Here's the component code:

```
import { TextField, Button } from '@mui/material'

const ContactForm = () => {

    return (
        <form
            name="contact-form"
            id="contact-form"
            method="post"
            data-netlify="true"
        >
            <input type="hidden" name="contact-form" value="contact" />
            <TextField
                label="Name"
                name="name"
                data-name="name"
                required
                fullWidth
                margin="normal"
            />
            <TextField
                label="Email"
                name="email"
                data-name="email"
                required
                fullWidth
                type="email"
                margin="normal"
            />
            <TextField
                label="Phone"
                name="phone"
                data-name="phone"
                required
                fullWidth
                type="tel"
                margin="normal"
            />
            <TextField
                label="Message"
                name="message"
                data-name="message"
                multiline
                rows={4}
                fullWidth
                margin="normal"
            />
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" value="enviar">
                Submit
            </Button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default ContactForm
```

As you can see, there's nothing special with this form.

I looked at Netlify's documentation and said that for some React projects, a hidden form was required to make the system detect all other forms. I did that and it is being detected by Netlify successfully, but the other form is just not being detected, thus, not working.

I looked at a similar issue: [Netlify form doesn't work with a Material-UI modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830094/netlify-form-doesnt-work-with-a-material-ui-modal)

However, the situation is a little different here since I'm not conditionally displaying the form, it should be built at run time

Thanks for the help

Here's the component code:

```
import { TextField, Button } from '@mui/material'

const ContactForm = () => {

    return (
        <form
            name="contact-form"
            id="contact-form"
            method="post"
            data-netlify="true"
        >
            <input type="hidden" name="contact-form" value="contact" />
            <TextField
                label="Name"
                name="name"
                data-name="name"
                required
                fullWidth
                margin="normal"
            />
            <TextField
                label="Email"
                name="email"
                data-name="email"
                required
                fullWidth
                type="email"
                margin="normal"
            />
            <TextField
                label="Phone"
                name="phone"
                data-name="phone"
                required
                fullWidth
                type="tel"
                margin="normal"
            />
            <TextField
                label="Message"
                name="message"
                data-name="message"
                multiline
                rows={4}
                fullWidth
                margin="normal"
            />
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" value="enviar">
                Submit
            </Button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default ContactForm
```

As you can see, there's nothing special with this form.

I looked at Netlify's documentation and said that for some React projects, a hidden form was required to make the system detect all other forms. I did that and it is being detected by Netlify successfully, but the other form is just not being detected, thus, not working.

I looked at a similar issue: [Netlify form doesn't work with a Material-UI modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830094/netlify-form-doesnt-work-with-a-material-ui-modal)

However, the situation is a little different here since I'm not conditionally displaying the form, it should be built at run time

Thanks for the help

Comment: you should add data-netlify="true" attribute on the every TextField , maybe that way it works

Comment: I haven't seen that solution before, is it something that you have tried?

Comment: I just saw that a few person did I'm not sure it solves your issue but worth to try , let me know about result pls if you try

Comment: FYI it didn't work. I'm still trying to understand what's the issue. If I put the form hardcoded on each page where I need it, it works just fine, but I'd rather use a component

Answer (score 0):

So, in the index.js page I was displaying this form and also some server side data as follows

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const response = await fetch("https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/MFL/109,49/forecast")
  const weatherData = await response.json()

  return {
    props: {
      forecast: weatherData.properties.periods[0].detailedForecast
    }
  }
}
```

Once I removed it, the form started to send submissions. However, now I have a different issue which is, all styles are broken if I'm not defining some server side props in the index.js page.

I will create a different question for that topic